# ¿Cómo puedo ver un JTable completo sin tapar el resto de componentes de mi JPanel?

Tags: java, jtable, jpanel

He creado un JTable sacando los datos de una base de datos mysql, el problema es que no se muestran los nombres de las columnas. Buscando en internet, encontré que debía de poner un JScrollPane, el problema es que si lo pongo, la tabla se ve correctamente, pero los demás elementos que tengo en el JPanel no. He probado otras formas de agregar JScrollPane, pero entonces me aparecen los demás elementos y no la tabla.

La forma de crear la tabla con el JScrollPane y que se vea es esta:

```
tabla = new JTable(numFil+1, numCol-4); // Se inicializa la tabla con el número de filas  y columnas de la BBDD.
tabla.setBounds(15, 15, 1312, 585); // Dimensiones de la tabla.
tabla.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1)); // Borde de la tabla.
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tabla); // Se inicia el JScrollPane para la tabla.
add(scrollPane); // Se agrega.
´´´
```

Comment: Hace tiempo que no programo GUIs así que no voy a darte una respuesta exacta, pero al hacer *add* al JPanel tendrías que usar alguna de las sobrecargas que permiten indicar al *LayoutManager* cómo gestionar este componente, dónde dibujarlo. Y el *setBounds* de la tabla probablemente ya no sea necesario (ya que ocupará el 100% del scrollPane).

Comment: @SJuan76 gracias, también me he dado cuenta de que lo agrega al JFrame no al JPanel, pero si intento ponerla en el panel no se ve.